# Spring Data JPA / Hibernate: How to avoid unnecessary JOIN when using the JOIN column in the same table

Tags: hibernate, join, spring-data-jpa

Lets assume the following association:

```
 @JoinColumn(
        name = "contract_id", nullable = false,
        foreignKey = ForeignKey(name = "fk_example__contract"),
 )
 val contract: Contract,
```

in an Entity called `Example`

If I query for contract.id, Spring Data JPA and Hibernate will create JOIN to the table contract, even if the column contract_id is within the same table `example`

```
fun findAllByContractId(contractId: Long, pageable: Pageable): Page<ExampleProjection>
```

Same effect with Criteria API

We can avoid that unnecessary JOIN by adding the following mapping:

````
//avoiding join to contract, if just using ```contract_id``` in where clause
@Column(name = "contract_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
var contractId: Long? = null
````

After adding this additional mapping, the LEFT OUTER JOIN to table `contract` disappears when using `findAllByContractId`

This solution has a disadvantage in my test case: The `contractId` property in the entity `Example`is null, after loading the entity with repsitory.getOne(id) (Spring Data JPA).

Is there a better way to avoid the join, if I just need to use a projection with `contractId` or if I just want to use it in where clause, if `contract_id` is in the same table `example`?

Comment: You can try `findAllByContract` instead of `findAllByContractId` and see if that helps. Also you can try `Example` searching and see if that helps. Finally if nothing does the sensible thing you can create a `@Query` method.

Comment: Of course with a native query in  @Query(native=true), we can solve it, but with a JPQL query, we have the same effect.

Comment: ManyToOne is default fetch type eager

Comment: We (almost) never use fetchType=EAGER. I consider it as antipattern. Default fetchtype is LAZY and then load with EntityGraph or JOIN FETCH if needed. Otherwise you lose flexibility to not load thigs if not needed.

Comment: I tried it with fetch type LAZY and findByContract and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

The column how you defined it should work just fine.

Maybe it is the problem how you load your data with repository.getOne(). Are you using it in test? Maybe you need to call `testEntityManager.clear()` so Hibernate can properly map the id column to your entity property